# How to replicate three plots next to each other with marginal plot on two of them?

Tags: r

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

I'm trying to replicate the theme of these graph using ggplot, I searched online for articles and question to show me how to assign these plots the right size and position and also to assign the tight dot shape,  and I found few articles that discussed changing position, I tried the following:

```
d1<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  filter(winner != "draw") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating, color = winner, shape = winner)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  # Just a guess to add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
  # Should "draw"s be colored or dropped?
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(cream = 16, charcoal = 17)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal")+ theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p.1<-ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
  geom_point(aes(color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  # Add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
  geom_point(aes(y = mean(charcoal_rating), color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17)) +
  # "draw"s should be dropped and removed from the title
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = NA)) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal") + theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 


p.01<-ggplot(d1, aes(x=cream_rating, y=charcoal_rating)) + 
  # Map winner on color. Add some transparency in case of overplotting
 geom_density2d(aes(color = winner), alpha = 0.2) +
  # Add the cross: Add geom_pints with one variable fixed on its mean
   scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17, 0)) +
  # "draw"s should be dropped and removed from the title
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cream = "seagreen4", charcoal = "chocolate3", draw = "blue")) +
  ggtitle("Rating of Cream vs Charcoal") +
  xlab("rating of cream") + ylab("rating of charcoal") + theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 

plot.1<-p.1


plot.02<-ggExtra::ggMarginal(p.01, type = "density",
  margins = 'both',
  size = 5,
  groupColour = TRUE,
  groupFill = TRUE
)
plot.02

require(gridExtra)
plot.1<-p.1
plot.2<-ggExtra::ggMarginal(p.1, type = "histogram")
grid.arrange(plot.1, plot.2, ncol=3)
plot.02
library(cowplot)

theme_set(theme_cowplot())

plot.1<-p.1
plot.2<-ggExtra::ggMarginal(p.1, type = "histogram")
plot.02
plot_grid(plot.1, plot.2, plot.02, labels = "AUTO")

cowplot::plot_grid(plot.1, plot.2, plot.02, labels = "AUTO")


library(magrittr)
library(multipanelfigure)
figure1 <- multi_panel_figure(columns = 2, rows = 1, panel_label_type = "none")
# show the layout
figure1

figure1 %<>%
  fill_panel(plot.1, column = 1, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(plot.2, column = 2, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(plot.02, column= 3, row = 1)  %<>%
figure1
```

This is my data set structure:

```
structure(list(rated = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), turns = c(13L, 16L, 61L, 61L, 95L, 
5L, 33L, 9L, 66L, 119L), victory_status = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("draw", "mate", "outoftime", 
"resign"), class = "factor"), winner = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("charcoal", "cream", 
"draw"), class = "factor"), increment_code = structure(c(3L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10+0", "15+0", 
"15+2", "15+30", "20+0", "30+3", "5+10"), class = "factor"), 
    cream_rating = c(1500L, 1322L, 1496L, 1439L, 1523L, 1250L, 
    1520L, 1413L, 1439L, 1381L), charcoal_rating = c(1191L, 1261L, 
    1500L, 1454L, 1469L, 1002L, 1423L, 2108L, 1392L, 1209L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks to @Stefan's suggestion (which was great help) in getting me this far.

Comment: your linked image is missing

Comment: Thank you @max ! I updated the question with the image.